# Functional composition with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic

My goal is to get composition of functions working with this **exact** syntax:

```
int main() {
    Function<std::string, int> f([](const std::string& s) {return s.length();});
    Function<int, double> g([](int x) {return x + 0.5;});
    Function<double, int> h([](double d) {return int(d+1);});
    std::cout << compose(g, f, "hello") << '\n';  // g(f("hello")) = 5.5
    std::cout << compose(h, g, f, "hello") << '\n';  // h(g(f("hello"))) = 6
}
```

By changing the syntax slightly so that the `"hello"` argument goes first, I have it working easily with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename D, typename R>
struct Function {
    using domain = const D&;
    using range = R;
    using function = std::function<range(domain)>;
    const function& f;
    Function (const function& f) : f(f) {}
    range operator()(domain x) const {return f(x);}
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct LastType {
    using Tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1, Tuple>::type;
};

template <typename F, typename G>
typename G::range compose (const typename F::domain& x, const G& g, const F& f) {
    return g(f(x));
}

template <typename F, typename... Rest>
auto compose (const typename LastType<Rest...>::type::domain& x, const F& f, const Rest&... rest) {
    return f(compose(x, rest...));
}

int main() {
    Function<std::string, int> f([](const std::string& s) {return s.length();});
    Function<int, double> g([](int x) {return x + 0.5;});
    Function<double, int> h([](double d) {return int(d+1);});
    std::cout << compose("hello", g, f) << '\n';  // g(f("hello")) = 5.5
    std::cout << compose("hello", h, g, f) << '\n';  // h(g(f("hello"))) = 6
}
```

Having done that, I thought it would be a trivial task to adapt the above code so that I get the exact syntax I want (i.e. with "hello" being at the end of the list), but it is turning more difficult than I thought.  I attempted the following, which does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename D, typename R>
struct Function {
    using domain = const D&;
    using range = R;
    using function = std::function<range(domain)>;
    const function& f;
    Function (const function& f) : f(f) {}
    range operator()(domain x) const {return f(x);}
};

template <typename F, typename G>
typename G::range compose (const G& g, const F& f, const typename F::domain& x) {
    return g(f(x));
}

template <typename F, typename... Rest>
auto compose (const F& f, const Rest&... rest) {
    return f(compose(rest...));
}

int main() {
    Function<std::string, int> f([](const std::string& s) {return s.length();});
    Function<int, double> g([](int x) {return x + 0.5;});
    Function<double, int> h([](double d) {return int(d+1);});
    std::cout << compose(g, f, "hello") << '\n';  // g(f("hello")) = 5.5
    std::cout << compose(h, g, f, "hello") << '\n';  // h(g(f("hello"))) = 6
}
```

And I don't know how to fix it. Can anybody help me fix this?

A new idea I've come up with is to define `compose_`, which will reorder the arguments of `args...` (by some `std::tuple` manipulation) so that the first element goes last and then passing that argument pack to `compose`.  This looks very messy though, and even if it works, there must be a more direct (and shorter) solution.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60c3af1faf41f0f6) ?

Comment: @ Piotr Skotnicki     Great!  I'm trying to figure out why yours compiles why mine does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about in this way?

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename D, typename R>
struct Function {
    using domain = const D&;
    using range = R;
    using function = std::function<range(domain)>;
    const function& f;
    Function (const function& f) : f(f) {}
    range operator()(domain x) const {return f(x);}
};

template <typename F, typename X = typename F::domain>
typename F::range compose (const F& f, const X & x) {
    return f(x);
}

template <typename F, typename... Rest>
typename F::range  compose (const F& f, const Rest&... rest) {
    return f(compose(rest...));
}

int main() {
    Function<std::string, int> f([](const std::string& s) {return    s.length();});
    Function<int, double> g([](int x) {return x + 0.5;});
    Function<double, int> h([](double d) {return int(d+1);});
    std::cout << compose(g, f, "hello") << '\n';  // g(f("hello")) = 5.5
    std::cout << compose(h, g, f, "hello") << '\n';  // h(g(f("hello"))) = 6
}
```

You can use `auto` for the returning type of `compose()` only in c++14 (if I'm not wrong).

<strike>Your version doesn't compile because your variadic version of `compose()` uses N variadic types and N arguments when the final (not varidic) uses 2 types and 3 arguments. In other words, the variadic version lost the final argument.</strike>
Your version doesn't compile because the final (not variadic version) is never used: the compiler chooses the variadic version. Adding `typename X = typename F::domain` (and changing `const typename F::domain&` with `const X&`) the final version is preferred and your code should compile (with c++14, at least) [corrected by  Piotr Skotnicki; thanks]

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: "*Your version don't compile because the variadic version of compose() is with N variadic types and N arguments when the final (not variac) is with 2 variadic types and 3 arguments.*", I think OP's code does not compile because whatever `Rest` deduces, it is an exact match compared to `const typename F::domain&`

Comment: @ Piotr: your right about one point: my explanation is wrong.

Comment: @Piotr: and, yes, your right: changing the template definition of the variadic version of OP's code from `template <typename G, typename F,>` to `template <typename G, typename F, typename X = typename F::domain>`, the OP's code compile

Comment: `typename X = typename F::domain` doesn't make much sense, since `X` will be deduced anyway

Comment: @Piotr: 
I'm not sure (I'm not really an expert) but I think the problem (in Prestokey code) is that the final (not variadic) version of `compose()` was expected to receive, as last parameter, a `type::domain` that in (in the examples) a` std::string const`. (continue)

Comment: @Piotr: (continue) In the `main()` function, the last parameter for `compose()` is a `char const *`, which can be converted to an `std::string const` but isn't, exactly, a `std::string const`. (continue)

Comment: @Piotr: (continue) So, for `compose(g, f, x)`, the compiler choose the variadic version of `compose()`, not the final version; in this way, the final version is never used, and the compiler is unable to close the chain. On the contrary, by introducing an additional type template (the default type is unnecessary), the final version (not variadic) corresponds to an exact match (where the last parameter is a generic type), is more specialized than the variadic version and, therefore, is selected. In other words, another way to fix the program was pass `std::string("hello")` instead of `"hello"`.

Comment: what is `typename X = typename F::domain` supposed to do in your code? `X` will be deduced, it's not set to `F::domain`

Comment: @Piotr: are you right: is unusefull. But my entire solution it's over-complicated; much more simple and elegant the User1149913 one.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the following also works:

```
template <typename T>
const T& compose (const T& t) {
    return t;
}

template <typename F, typename... Rest>
typename F::range compose(const F& f, Rest... rest) {
    return f(compose(rest...));
}
```

Comment: Simpler than my solution. Nice.